# Exception "MessageProperties object has been disposed" when trying to get the client IP in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I use this code for get client IP in WCF service:

```
    public string GetClientIP()
    {
        var context = OperationContext.Current;
        MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
        var endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        string ip = endpoint.Address;
        return ip;
    }
```

when you try to run - throw exception "The System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties object has been disposed".

This code does not work in one WCF service. Its web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

It is rest WCF service. Caller service-method signature like this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "{someParameter}/MyMethod")]
public string MyMethod(string someParameter, Stream stream)
{
    var ip = GetClientIP();
}
```

Search in Google nothing. Got any ideas?

Comment: try `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` instead